# Proper use Producer/Consumer Pattern with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I'm working on project with the following workflow:

**Part One:**

- Read long list of URLs from a file (~100 000 URL) line by line
- Add each line to a blocking collection Q (producer)
- For each URL in Q, do some processing: download and parse data (consumer)
- Add processed data to a list L

**Part two:**

Now, I have 100 000 records to save to the database. I have to update existing records add non existing ones(no duplication) using **Entity Framework**. To do so, i have two scenarios:

1- When processing URL in Q(consumer), save one record to the database
==> many requests to the database, waste of time with entity framework, locks every time we will add to the database to check if element is not duplicate

2- Wait the end of part one and do one big request to the database to add all new records and update existing ones.
==> don't take full advantage of running the consumer asynchronously and in multi-threading context as I have to wait for all element in Q to be processed

I thought it would be better if i could do middle solution: Add another blocking collection Q2 so every consumed element in part one will be added to Q2. When the size of Q2 reaches a fixed optimal number (example 1000 element), start the consumer of Q2 that will add 1000 record to the database. 
So I'm thinking about adding another producer/consumer mechanism to my solution.

Is there a better way to resolve this issue. NB: My first priority is speed